# The meaning of the structure “should something do”

Tags: sentence-meaning

> But, he said, 'there is no evidence of the political will necessary to make this happen ... **in particular from the stronger countries**, all of whom will lose out massively **should the euro zone eventually collapse**'.

[original text](https://www.scmp.com/article/1002684/bankers-bracing-challenging-times-ahead)

I found this paragraph hard to understand. Could you help me analyse it grammatically? Especially the bold lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**should** *noun* *verb*" is essentially the same as "if *noun* *verbs*".  So in this case, "should the euro zone eventually collapse" means "if the euro zone eventually collapses."

This is a use of *should* as a modal to form the subjunctive, and you do not conjugate the main verb, which is why it's *collapse* and not *collapses*.

The part about "in particular from the stronger countries" is the speaker saying that the political will is lacking *particularly from the stronger countries*.  I don't think it's a very well-crafted sentence, but the speaker might have been speaking "off the cuff", instead of from prepared notes.

Answer (score 0):

This is the (rather literary) use of inversion for a conditional clause.

*Should the euro zone eventually collapse* is exactly the same as *if the euro zone should eventually collapse.*

Other examples:

> Had I seen him -> If I had seen him

> Were it to happen -> If it were to happen

It is only available with a modal or *had*, and as stangdon's answer suggests, the modal can usually be omitted from the uninverted form with *if*. (*If it happened*)

In modern writing I think you'll find it only with *had*, *were*, and *should*. In older writing you might find other modals.